# Practicing programming : solving crescent difficulty problems

Tags: complexity-theory

As everyone knows, real life problems when it comes to programming are numerous and often unexpected. Sometimes, those problems even are hard to solve, and without being trained to recognize them, you can quickly get stuck. I like challenge, because the more you get confronted to a recurrent situation, the less time you need to come up with an efficient answer -in time complexity, for instance- when you encounter a similar issue.

This leads to my question :

Does anybody know a good book, or any kind of support, that remains language independent enough, providing problems that tends to be hard at some point, probably crescent difficulty, to practice coding. I mean, these problems that are addictive and interesting, and you feel a real achievement when you solve them. Something like, if you don't find a trick to get your algorithm time-linear, while there also is an expensive brute-force version, it will lead you to failure.

Thanks already for your suggestions.

Comment: Project Euler (http://projecteuler.net/) is quite good for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692/where-can-you-find-fun-educational-programming-challenges

Comment: oh, right, I didn't see this one after my search... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

- [Code Kata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/2007/01/code_kata_backg.html)
- [High School Programming Language](http://hs.spoj.pl/problems/set1/)
- [France IOI](http://www.france-ioi.org/train/algo/index.php) (*in French, but there's tons of exercises*)

Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
(btw, I'm french, so the last one shouldn't be a problem :p) Mais toi aussi je crois, haha.

Comment: Yes indeed :p Again, have fun coding :)